# openui5/sapui5: Change parts of a page controlled by router

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I like to implement a master-detail-like UI5 Application without using the SplitApp-control in sap.m. Instead I want to have a Page with fixed content on the left and a `<NavContainer>` on the right. Based on the URL (router) I like to change the content of the `<NavContainer>` *only* - not the entire page.

So far my initial page renders correctly. But if I cange my URL to `#trans` the *whole* page changes to my `previewTransaction.view.xml`, not only the `<NavContainer>` part.

Whats wrong?

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge' />
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8' />
    <title>Hello UI5!</title>

    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' type='text/javascript' 
      src='https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
      data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
      data-sap-ui-frameOptions='allow'
    >
    </script>

    <script>
         sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.require([], function () {

                var app = new sap.m.App("appId");
                appGlobals.app = app;
                var rootView = new sap.ui.view({id: "mainId", viewName: "./appRoot", type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
                app.addPage(rootView); // app contains views
                app.placeAt("content");

                // setup router
                jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.Router");
                jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger");
                jQuery.sap.require("./routes"); // load ./routes.js
                var router = new sap.ui.core.routing.Router(myroutes, myRoutesDefaultSettings, null, myTargetsConfig); // myroutes defined in routes.js
                router.initialize();
            });
        });
  </script>

  </head>
  <body class='sapUiBody' id="content">
  </body>
</html>
```

**appRoot.view.xml:**

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
    <Page> 
        <content>
            <l:VerticalLayout id="containerLayout" width="100%" height="100%">
                <l:BlockLayout id="BlockLayout">
                    <l:BlockLayoutRow>
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell>

                            <!-- 'Master' -->
                            <mvc:XMLView viewName="xx.views.SearchControlPanel"></mvc:XMLView>

                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell width="3">

                            <!-- 'Detail' -->
                            <NavContainer id="nc_previewContent" height="100%" navigate="nc_Nav">
                                <mvc:XMLView viewName="./preview"></mvc:XMLView>
                            </NavContainer>

                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                    </l:BlockLayoutRow>
                </l:BlockLayout>
            </l:VerticalLayout>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

**routes.js:**

```
var myRoutesDefaultSettings = {
    viewType: "XML",
    clearTarget: true
};

var myroutes = [
    {
        name: "main",
        pattern: "",
        target: "welcome"
    },
    {
        name: "transactions",
        pattern: "trans", // handle #trans URL endings
        target: "transactions"
    }
];

var myTargetsConfig = {

    welcome: {
        viewName: "./appRoot",
        controlId: "appId",
        controlAggregation: "pages",
        clearAggregation: false
    },
    transactions: {
        viewName: "./previewTransactions",
        controlId: "nc_previewContent", // id of NavContainer in ppRoot.view.xml
        controlAggregation: "pages", // aggregation of a NavContainer is named 'pages'
        clearAggregation: false
    }

};
```

Comment: Why not use the built-in SplitApp? It's responsive, documented, tested, no need for lame hacks just to navigate, etc...

Comment: 1) You cant customize it 2) what if you like to have three (or more) detail pages?

Comment: What do you want to customize? And you can probably have hundreds of detail pages (well... not at the same time), so it would help to understand your usecase.

Comment: the "at the same time" is the issue here. I like to have an app where I can have as many "i-framish" elements as I like (visible at the same time) and have full contol over their placement, size, layout, colors, headlines, borders, ...

Comment: Make a detail page with *n* panels, each panel contains a view (customized to fit your needs).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the id defined in router (routes.js) - `controlId:"nc_previewContent"`. Since the NavContainer is sitting within the appRoot view ( whose id is -main), the correct id of the NavContainer will be (since Ids of controls in XML views are prefixed with View Id):

```
 controlId: "mainId--nc_previewContent"
```

I changed the your code to the above Id, also made the following changes:

1. Change id of controlId in router to : `mainId--nc_previewContent`
2. Changed the router from `sap.ui.core.routing.Router` to `sap.m.routing.Router`

It's working as expected ( only NavContainer is changed). Code follows below:

index.html

```
<script>
        sap.ui.localResources("/");
         sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
            sap.ui.require([], function () {

                var app = new sap.m.App("appId");
                //appGlobals.app = app;
                var rootView = new sap.ui.view({id: "mainId", viewName: "com.sap.appRoot", type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
                app.addPage(rootView); // app contains views
                app.placeAt("content");

                // setup router
                jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.routing.Router");
                jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.routing.HashChanger");
                jQuery.sap.require("com.sap.routes"); // load ./routes.js
                var router = new sap.m.routing.Router(myroutes, myRoutesDefaultSettings, null, myTargetsConfig); // myroutes defined in routes.js
                router.initialize(); 
            });
        });
        </script>
```

routes.js

```
var myroutes = [
    {
        name: "main",
        pattern: "",
        target: "welcome"
    },
    {
        name: "second",
        pattern: "second", // handle #trans URL endings
        target: "second"
    }
];

var myTargetsConfig = {

    welcome: {
        viewName: "com.sap.viewRight",
        controlId: "mainId--nc_previewContent",
        controlAggregation: "pages",
        clearAggregation: false
    },
    second: {
        viewName: "com.sap.viewRight2",
        controlId: "mainId--nc_previewContent", // id of NavContainer in ppRoot.view.xml
        controlAggregation: "pages", // aggregation of a NavContainer is named 'pages'
        clearAggregation: false
    }

};
```

Let me know if you need additional information.